# Color System in Processing Paint-like Program

Tags: variables, while-loop, processing, paint, processing.js

I am building a paint-like program in processing. I want to be able to adjust the r, g, and b values of the pen color. What I did is use the 'r' key to allow the user to change r. After hitting 'r' they use the '+' and '-' keys to adjust it. Then you hit 'd', and it finishes. '+' and '-' are already used for pen size so I had to do it this way. But when I run the code and hit r it freezes up and stops responding. Does anyone know what is wrong.

Here is the problematic part of the code:

```
if(key == 'r'){ // Activates if 'r' is pressed
  actr = true; // Sets actr = to true
  while (actr = true) { // Goes until actr is false
    if (key == '=') { // Activates is '=' is pressed
      r = r ++; // Increases r by one
    }

    if (key == '-'){ // Activates if '-' is pressed
      r = r --; // Decreases r by one
    }

    if (key == 'd') { // Activates if 'd' is pressed
      actr = false; // Sets actr = to false
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the full code: http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/226658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few problems. First of all, look at this line:

```
while (actr = true) { // Goes until actr is false
```

You're not checking equality here, you're assigning the value of `true` to your `actr` variable, which will also evaluate to `true`. In other words, that will never be false. Instead, you should use:

```
while (actr == true) {
```

Or even better:

```
while (actr) {
```

However, even when you fix that, your while loop will still never exit. This is because you're **busy waiting** and blocking the program from continuing. **This will prevent Processing from ever changing the `key` variable.**

Instead of busy waiting, just keep track of which mode you're in, which determines what the + and - keys do. You could use a series of booleans:

```
boolean size = true;
boolean red = false;
boolean green = false;
boolean blue = false;

void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'r'){ // Activates if 'r' is pressed

    if (key == '=') { 
      if(size){
         x++;
      }
      else if(red){
        r++;
      }
    }
    else if (key == '-'){
      if(size){
         x++;
      }
      else if(red){
        r++;
      }
    }

    if (key == 'd') { // Activates if 'd' is pressed
      size = true;
      red = false;
      blue = false;
      green = false;
    }
    else if(key == 'r'){
      size = false;
      red = true;
      blue = false;
      green = false;
    }
  }
}
```

That's just one approach, and I didn't include all of the code, but that should be a better general idea than your busy waiting.

Comment: Do you think i could create a custom function with the while loop and have it return r every time it loops?

Comment: @SnapDraggen Why would you want to? Processing uses an event system, so you don't have to busy wait like that.